# Steps for adding a new codec support to VLC

Tags: vlc, libvlc, libavcodec, video-player

I have a task of adding a new decoder support to VLC. I have downloaded the latest version of the code from GIT. My decoder is a custom and doesn't have a container format. If takes a encoder input file and provides me with the YUv file dump of the same.

Inorder to add this decoder to VLC framework i should be creating a VLC plug-in. However, i have searched a lot and have not found any steps for creating a VLC plug-in. I can create both a `.dll` and `.lib` out of my decoder. Can somebody please guide me regarding how to proceed regarding this issue.

This post is not a duplicate of:

[Integrating a video codec into gstreamer or vlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516024/integrating-a-video-codec-into-gstreamer-or-vlc)

Any hints or steps for proceeding will be really helpful to me. Please help regarding the same. Thanks in advance.